# Which maxim Elasticsearch java client version is compatible with 1.5.2?

Tags: elasticsearch, java-11

I have Elasticsearch version 1.5.2 running and Java 8 application that is connected to it using 1.5.2 client. I would like to upgrade the Java version to Zulu 11 and found that Java 11 is supported by Elasticsearch after version 5.6.x.

Do I need to upgrade Elasticsearch to 5.6.x as well or upgrading Elasticsearch java client is enough? What maximum java client version of Elasticsearch I can use to connect to Elasticsearch 1.5.2?

Comment: as a general comment - 1.5 is super, super old, as is 5.X, and both are no longer supported. you really need to be using 7.X as 8.0 is not far off being released

Comment: Also, there probably is no sane way for zero-downtime upgrade so you might want to just reindex everything into the new cluster.